# Can't centre link

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a link, that nothing I do will centre it. I'm not sure which bit of css is stoping it from working.

The html is:

```
<a href="/wp1/product-tag/armani-jeans/?action=yith-woocompare-add-product&amp;id=28674&amp;_wpnonce=95c22023b0" class="compare button" data-product_id="28674">Compare</a>
```

and the css acting on it (from when I inspect it) is:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {margin-top:1em}
.woocommerce a.button {font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
line-height: 1;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
font-family: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
overflow: visible;
padding: .618em 1em;
font-weight: 700;
border-radius: 3px;
left: auto;
color: #515151;
background-color: #ebe9eb;
border: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
display: inline-block;
background-image: none;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
text-shadow: none;}
```

I just can't work out what combination of things I need to override in order to centre it!

Any advice would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Centre it to what? to a div? to the page? can you post a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: Center it to the div it's in. I'm not sure how to do a fiddle I'm afraid :(

Comment: go to http://www.jsfiddle.net and paste your css and html there then click on save and share the link

Comment: @PeterKirkwood now try to this css .woocommerce ul.products li.product{text-align:center;}

Comment: @RohitAzad That did it! So simple! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it pls?

Comment: @PeterKirkwood I have allready post to my answer please check it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi now try** to this way i thing if you used to this `css` than your problem is  solve

now define your `.woocommerce ul.products li.product` `text-align` `center` in your `css`

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product{text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using

```
.woocommerce a.button{ text-align:center}
 or 
.woocommerce a.compare{ text-align:center}
```

hopefully it will